# AC power supply issue

Tags: electricity, electrically-conductive

If I'm getting a voltage of 240 V on an open circuit, the voltage drops to about 200 V when a heavy load is connected to it. (Plasma Cutter in my case. Hence it wont work)

Further on, is there a way to compute the drop in voltage if I know the voltage on the open circuit as well as the wattage of the load.

We tried using Stabilizer but plasma is very sensitive towards voltage. And Stabilizer has response time more than sensitivity of plasma. Till stabilizer stabilizes voltage until plasma get turn off.

Comment: Sounds like inadaquite wiring to me... Do you know what size the wire is on the 240 line? And what the power requirements is for the plasma cutter? Or, are you using a transformer to get the 240, from either 120 or 480?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are really asking, but in general, think of the power supply as being a Thevnin source.  If you don't know what that is, look it up.  It's a standard term that is surely well described out there.

Basically, to first approximation, you have:

[image]

When the power supply is open circuit, no current flows thru R1, so there is no voltage across R1, so the power supply output is just V1.  When the load draws current, R1 will drop some voltage, and the power supply output is V1 minus the voltage dropped by R1.  That voltage drop will be the current times the resistance of R1.

By knowing the current the load is drawing at whatever voltage it is actually given, and knowing the open-circuit voltage, you can compute the value of R1 by using Ohm's law.  You can derive the load current from the voltage presented to the load and the power it is drawing *at that voltage*.